# Visa for getting sweat equity in US company?

Tags: usa

I'm an Indian citizen residing in India. Right now I don't have any US visa. I've worked with a US citizen(residing in US) to develop a software product. Now we are in a position to establish the company in the US. My partner is offering 20% equity in the US company. This is sweat equity since I'm not actually investing money into the company. My contribution is in product development.

My question is:

**1. Which visa is required to get such a ownership in the US company?**

**2. What is the best option for me to secure the green card?**

**Edit:**

Answers to the comments:
The 20% ownership is a reward for the work I do. If required I'll be travelling to US to have the agreements signed.

Comment: You don’t require a visa to own any shared in a US company. A visa is required to come to the US, not to own part of a US company.

Comment: Are you actually travelling to the US to do work in establishing this company? Also do you already own equity in the company or will this equity be a reward for the work you do?

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Which visa is required to get such a ownership in the US company?

You don’t need a visa to have equity in a USA company. You don’t even need to live in the USA (although FinCom rules make it hard but not impossible for non-USA residents to buy stocks in publicly traded stocks)

> 2. What is the best option for me to secure the green card?

You would likely go for an investment visa. However, I assume your company is still very very small (less than five partners given your equity). It’s hard to prove valuation of such a startup. Otherwise you could just declare MyLittleLLC LLC to have a valuation of $20 trillion. So proving that your company is worth enough for an investment visa is non-trivial, you have to convert your equity to cash in a relatively arms length transaction.

So... do a Series A round of raising venture capital. Use that to sell all or part of your equity for $1 million or negotiate a $1 million payout.

Then take that $1 million, deduct some overhead for transaction costs, and invest in another company for an [EB-5 visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EB-5_visa?wprov=sfti1), most likely through a regional center.

Comment: @MattDouhan this answer appears to be answering the second part of the question, which is about the best way to get a green card.

Comment: This is not needed just to own shares but is a way to visa and green card

Comment: @MattDouhan that's a better comment :-)  One of these answers ought to point out that there's no need for a US visa for a foreigner to earn equity in a US company by doing work while outside the US.  So far, that information is only to be found in comments.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier if you kept product development in India, hiring locally, at least initially. There are two chances for getting a US visa and ultimately green card:

- The company makes enough money that you can sell some of your shares, and qualify for the [EB-5 Immigrant Investor Program](https://www.uscis.gov/eb-5).
- After a year you should qualify for an [L-1A Intracompany Transferee Executive or Manager](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/l-1a-intracompany-transferee-executive-or-manager) or [L-1B Intracompany Transferee Specialized Knowledge](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/l-1b-intracompany-transferee-specialized-knowledge).